# How can i show that this equation is true given 4 points as pronumerals

Tags: geometry

> The points *A*(*a*, 0) and *Q*(*q*, 0) are points on the positive x-axis, and the 
>   points *B*(0, *b*) and *P*(0, *p*) lie on the positive y-axis. Show that AB$^2$ − AP$^2$ = QB$^2$ − QP$^2$ .

How can i approach a question like this?,im fairly new to working with pro-numerals instead of numbers.I tried doing the slope intercept formula on each but i just got confused every time since there are no numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the Pythagoras Theorem to the four hypotenuses

$$AB^2 - AP^2 = (a^2+b^2)-(a^2+ p^2) =( q^2+b^2)-(q^2+ p^2) =QB^2-QP^2$$